# Android Espresso : select an item from a spinner in a webview

Tags: android, webview, android-espresso

In a payment Webview I'm trying to select the month and/or the year (spinner) via an Espresso Test. When I use "webclick" nothing append.

The webview part:

```
<form method="post" action="https://mercanet.bnpparibas.net/cgis-payment-mercanet/demo/callresource?rsc=creditcard" name="DATA_CAPTURE">
<span id="span_sips_card_number_title" class="sips_card_number_title"> N° de carte :  </span>
<select name="CARD_VAL_MONTH" size="1" class="sips_expiry_month_card_input">
<option value="01" selected="selected"> 01-Janvier</option>
<option value="02"> 02-Février</option>
<option value="03"> 03-Mars</option>
<option value="04"> 04-Avril</option>
<option value="05"> 05-Mai</option>
<option value="06"> 06-Juin</option>
<option value="07"> 07-Juillet</option>
<option value="08"> 08-Août</option>
<option value="09"> 09-Septembre</option>
<option value="10"> 10-Octobre</option>
<option value="11"> 11-Novembre</option>
<option value="12"> 12-Décembre</option></select>
<input size="20" maxlength="19" autocomplete="off" name="CARD_NUMBER" id="CARD_NUMBER" class="sips_card_number_input" value="" type="text">
<span id="ID_EXPIRE_FIN" class="sips_expiry_date_card_title">  Expire fin :  </span>
<span id="ID_SLASH" class="sips_expiry_date_card_title"> / </span>
<select name="CARD_VAL_YEAR" size="1" class="sips_expiry_year_card_input">
<option value="17" selected="selected"> 2017</option>
<option value="18"> 2018</option>
<option value="19"> 2019</option>
<option value="20"> 2020</option>
<option value="21"> 2021</option>
<option value="22"> 2022</option>
<option value="23"> 2023</option>
<option value="24"> 2024</option>
<option value="25"> 2025</option>
<option value="26"> 2026</option>
<option value="27"> 2027</option>
</select><br><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function InfoCvv() {
window.open('/images/logo_serveur/commun/cryptogramme_light.fr.html','A1','width=700,height=450, status=no, directories=no, toolbar=no, location=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=no')
}
// -->
</script>
<a href="javascript:InfoCvv()" onmouseover="window.status='N° de contrôle au dos de la carte'" class="sips_cryptogram_example"> <span id="span_sips_popup_message" class="sips_popup_message">N° de contrôle au dos de la carte</span> </a>&nbsp;:&nbsp;<input size="3" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off" name="CVV_KEY" id="CVV_KEY" class="sips_cryptogram_code_input" value="" type="text"><div class="sips_bloc_info_cvv"></div><br><br>
<span id="span_sips_submit_message" class="sips_submit_message"> Vous avez complété correctement le formulaire, vous pouvez </span>
<input name="USER" id="USER" value="628359@082584341411111.170116" type="hidden">
<input name="MERCHANT_ID" id="MERCHANT_ID" value="082584341411111" type="hidden">
<input name="MERCHANT_COUNTRY" id="MERCHANT_COUNTRY" value="fr" type="hidden">
<input name="CARD_TYPE" id="CARD_TYPE" value="CB" type="hidden">
<input name="CARD_MODE" id="CARD_MODE" value="CARTE" type="hidden">
<input name="CUSTOMER_COUNTRY" id="CUSTOMER_COUNTRY" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="PAIEMENT" value="VALIDER" class="sips_submit_button" type="submit"></form>
```

I used:

```
onWebView(withId(R.id.webview_payment)).forceJavascriptEnabled();
```

and try to simulate a click on the month and/or the year with these two methods:

```
onWebView(withId(R.id.webview_payment))
.withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME,"sips_expiry_year_card_input"))
.perform(webClick());
```

or

```
onWebView(withId(R.id.webview_payment))
.withElement(findElement(Locator.NAME,"CARD_VAL_MONTH"))
.perform(webClick());
```

None of these methods works (no dropdown). I got in debug mode the response:

```
brandNew = false
result = Evaluation: status: 0 value: null hasMessage: false message: null
```

Do you know why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Found what's wrong. The webclick works (field is selected) but no dropdown is showed. Then we have to select the option with Locator.XPATH.

So in this case the solution to select another month and years is:

```
    onWebView(withId(R.id.webview_payment))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.NAME,"CARD_VAL_MONTH"))
            .perform(webClick());

    onWebView(withId(R.id.webview_payment))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH,"//option[@value='02']"))
            .perform(webClick());


    onWebView(withId(R.id.webview_payment))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.NAME,"CARD_VAL_YEAR"))
            .perform(webClick());

    onWebView(withId(R.id.webview_payment))
            .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH,"//option[@value='18']"))
            .perform(webClick());
```